# Wpf Prism Resize Interaction Window

Tags: request, resize, window, prism, interaction

I am currently using the InteractionRequest feature of Prism to get confirmed data from DialogWindow.
Everything is fine until here.

The problem is user can resize the interaction window.
I could not find a easy way to do that.

Is there any idea ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You could not find an easy way to do what exactly?

Comment: resize the window

Comment: Isn't the user doing that?

Comment: Yes, the user should resize the window. But the window is not resizable. I am using Prism interactionrequest feature. But It does not allow me to configure it